# Word VBA - select in the table from given word to the end of paragraph but not entire cell

Tags: vba, ms-word, find

Trying to select and mark with red the specified text beginning from *"Depend"* to the end of the cell, **but not the entire cell**.
Sample of code:

```
With Selection
        Set obj_Tbl = .Tables(1)
        .Tables(1).Columns(2).Select ' Why so stupid? there is the conditional formatting
        For Each obj_Row In obj_Tbl.Rows
           With obj_Row.Cells(3)
                If InStr(1, obj_Row.Cells(3), "Depend") > 0 Then
                    obj_Row.Cells(3).Range.Characters(InStr(1, obj_Row.Cells(3), "Depend")).Select
                    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
                    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
                    Selection.Font.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0)
                End If
           End With
       Next 
End With
```

This works fine when the "Depend" is written in one row. But if the text looks like

```
Depends from Something 
Too Long to Be Shown In One Line
```

I have the trouble with selection which selects only one row.

```
Selection.EndOf Unit:=wdParagraph 'selects the entire cell
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdParagraph 'is not supported
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MoveRight` and calculate the units to move right from `Length of the Cell - Your Current Position`.

```
Sub Test()
Dim count As Long
With Selection
        Set obj_Tbl = .Tables(1)
        .Tables(1).Columns(2).Select
         For Each obj_Row In obj_Tbl.Rows
           With obj_Row.Cells(3)
                If InStr(1, obj_Row.Cells(3), "Depend") > 0 Then
                    obj_Row.Cells(3).Range.Characters(InStr(1, obj_Row.Cells(3), "Depend")).Select
                    count = Len(obj_Row.Cells(3).Range) - InStr(1, obj_Row.Cells(3), "Depend")
                    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=count - 2, Extend:=wdExtend
                    Selection.Font.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0)
                End If
           End With
       Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!